# Flutter RefreshIndicator indicating but not refreshing

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been reading all over the web and I can't find out what's wrong with my code.

Could anybody spare some minutes to lend me a hand?

Here's the code, basically I have a futurebuilder with a refreshindicator that uses the same function, but it is not working.

The Refresh function dumps an api to SQFlite.

```
class _MyTasksListViewState extends State<MyTasksListView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<OT>>(
      future: buildList(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return RefreshIndicator(
              child: ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!
                    .map((ot) => ListTile(
                          title: Text("Numero de OT: " + ot.ot.toString()),
                          subtitle: Text("OT Original: " + ot.otOriginal),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushNamed('/Tareas', arguments: {
                              'Tareas': ot.tareas,
                            });
                          },
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
              onRefresh: () => buildList());
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List<OT>> buildList() async {
    refresh(context);
    List<OT> lista = [];
    Database database = await initDB();
    var otFromDB = await database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 'ots'");
    var tareasFromDB = await database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 'tareas'");
    for (var i in otFromDB) {
      OT ot = OT.fromArray(i);
      for (var tarea in tareasFromDB) {
        if (tarea['otID'] == ot.ot) {
          ot.tareas.add(Tarea.fromArray(tarea));
        }
      }
      lista.add(ot);
    }
    return lista;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The both calls are returning diffrenet referances

```dart
    return FutureBuilder<List<OT>>(
      future: buildList(), // <--
```

and

```dart
onRefresh: () => buildList() // <--
```

so we have to unify the references to get the expected behavior 
1- define local Future variable

```dart
class _MyTasksListViewState extends State<MyTasksListView> {
   late Future<List<OT>> list; // <---
```

2- initialize the variable with `buildList()`

```dart
@override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  list = buildList(); // <--
}
```

3- give our future `list` to `FutureBuilder`

```dart
    return FutureBuilder<List<OT>>(
      future: list, // <--
```

4- `onRefresh` will change the state of our `list` variable

```dart
onRefresh: () =>  setState(()=> list = buildList())
```

that is it, I hope my answer can help you